# Question about prime ideals and Quotient rings

Tags: maximal-and-prime-ideals, quotient-spaces, integral-domain, quotient-group

I`m struggling with the following solution I wanted to use:

Let S := $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z] /(z^2-xy) \cong \mathbb{C}[x,y,\sqrt{xy}]$

Then $S/(x-y) \cong \mathbb{C}[x,x,\sqrt{x^2}] = \mathbb{C}[x]$, which is an integral domain.

Hence $(x-y)$ is prime in S, but $$xy-y^2=y(x-y) \in (x-y)$$ and $$xy-y^2 = (\sqrt{xy}-y)(\sqrt{xy}+y),$$
where neither of the last two factors is in $(x-y)$, which means $(x-y)$ is not prime.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: you're messing up with a square root. Root of a square of $x$ is not only $x$, so better hold to notation with $z$. To be more precise, the equality with the ring of polynomials with one variable does not hold.

Comment: Could I then say that
$$S/(x-y)=\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]/(z^2-xy)/(x-y) \cong \mathbb{C}[x,z]/(z^2-x^2)?$$
or how do I deal with the double quotient?

Comment: Yes. Then you could use Chinese Remainder Theorem. Or you just explain directly why this quotient is not an integral domain and hence (x-y) is not prime